# Can I have one class instance that returns another class instance?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to have one object that returns another object and passes some data to all the micro instances. This is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
export class Macro {
  constructor(props) {
    return (props) => {
      return Micro(props)
    }
  }
}

export class Micro {
  constructor(props) {
    this.macro = props
  }
}

let MicroInstance = new Macro({'happy': true})
let instance = new MicroInstance()
console.log(instance.macro.happy) // true
```

This throws an error:

```
  _classCallCheck(this, Macro);
                        ^

ReferenceError: Macro is not defined
```

**Update 1)**

Here's a more realistic use case for this. I'm trying to create a custom error object that uses info from a definition class, that way I don't have to keep passing all the same parameters to the `LangError` class.

```
let languages = {
  "en": {
    "login_errors": {
      "invalid_name": "Invalid Name: {name}!"
    }
  },
  "jp": {
    "login_errors": {
      "invalid_name": "無効な名前: {name}"
    }
  },
  "es": {
    "login_errors": {
      "invalid_name": "Nombre no válido: {name}!"
    }
  }
}

let LangError = new LangErrorDefinition({languages, nestedLocalesProp: 'login_errors'})
let error = new LangError('invalid_name', { name: 'Thomas' })
console.log(error.messages)

// { en: 'Invalid Name: Thomas!',
//   jp: '無効な名前: Thomas',
//   es: 'Nombre no válido: Thomas!' }
```

**Update 2)**

Using `Jonathan Lonowski`'s answer it works here [jsfiddle](https://jsbin.com/qafodamaba/edit?js,console).

```
class Macro {
  constructor(props) {
    return () => {
      return new Micro(props)
    }
  }
}

class Micro {
  constructor(props) {
    this.macro = props
  }
}

let MicroInstance = new Macro({'happy': true})
let instance = new MicroInstance()
console.log(instance.macro.happy) // true
```

However it's still giving me a babel error in my local file.

```
/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/project/test/error-suite.js:99
  _classCallCheck(this, Macro);
                        ^

ReferenceError: Macro is not defined
    at new Macro (error-suite.js:94:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (error-suite.js:108:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at loader (/Users/thomasreggi/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/thomasreggi/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:161:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasreggi/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:162:7)
```

**Update 3)**

The error above is due to having commend Japanese characters, I'm using `babel-node` and `2015` and `react` presets.

https://gist.github.com/reggi/cb9e83ce74de17da1ca2935b0bb3ff1d

Comment: This is ES6 correct? Are you sure the environment you're running this script in supports it?

Comment: I don't know this new JS stuff well - but are you sure you want to return object from constructor? There could be a factory method, but to return anything from constructor sounds like a great viciousness to me.

Comment: @NickZuber It is ES6, I don' think this is the correct way to do this.
@JanTuroň I want to return the object from the constructor because the `Macro` object is a factory for the `Micro`.

Comment: But the intention itself is so outrageous that any sane language forbids that syntactically. Maybe ES6 is an exception. Just imagine: `var x = new Foo;` - screw you, I'm not returning `Foo`, but something else.

Comment: The `ReferenceError` suggests a separate problem within `error-suite.js`. Is the 1st snippet, that defines the classes, from that file? If not, how are these classes being imported?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski It's just a file with that exact code in it `babel-node ./error-suite.js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. When a constructor returns any object, including a function, `new` will return that object as-is instead of the *instance* it created.

```
console.log(MicroInstance instanceof Macro);    // false
console.log(MicroInstance instanceof Function); // true
```

Though, with this in mind, `Macro` (or `LangErrorDefinition`) could just be a function and what it returns could be a new class (e.g., `ModifiedMicro`).

This can still make use of `Micro` through inheritance (`extends`), to avoid redefining the majority of the class for each `ModifiedMicro` created in a closure (`Macro`).

```
export class Micro {
  constructor(props, ...args) {
    this.macro = props;
    this.micro = args;
  }
}

export function Macro(props) {
  return class ModifiedMicro extends Micro {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(props, ...args);
    }
  };
}

let MicroInstance = Macro({'happy': true}) // no need for `new`
let instance = new MicroInstance('one', 'two')

console.log(instance.macro.happy) // true
console.log(instance.micro)       // ['one', 'two']

console.log(instance instanceof Micro); // true
```

---

[original answer]

The `constructor` for `Macro` has 2 issues currently:

1. The `props` argument is declared twice.

   ```
   constructor(props) {   // 1st
     return (props) => {  // 2nd
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```

   The 2nd declaration will be provided to `Micro(props)` due to variable shadowing, but only the 1st is given a value in your usage:

   ```
   let MicroInstance = new Macro({'happy': true}) // 1st
   let instance = new MicroInstance(/* props */)  // 2nd
   ```
2. Missing `new` when returning `Micro(props)`:

   ```
   return new Micro(props)
   ```

   Without that, you should see a `TypeError`:

   > Class constructor Micro cannot be invoked without 'new'

Adjusting for these, the `console.log()` should report `true` as you expected:

```
export class Macro {
  constructor(props) { // keep 1st `props`, removing 2nd
    return () => {
      return new Micro(props)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with 2 updates, with the use case I'm presenting I feel that new should be called when the error is created no? Is it ok to call new from within the Macro returned anon-function if it's an error object? 

The second issue is that your answer isnt' working with my local babel, I get the error described above.

Comment: I tracked down the error here's the file. It's because of the Japanese commend chars. https://gist.github.com/reggi/cb9e83ce74de17da1ca2935b0bb3ff1d

Comment: @ThomasReggi Hmm. Works for me copying the "raw" file. Do you know what encoding your editor is saving the file with? Node generally defaults/assumes UTF-8, so other encodings can cause odd results with higher code point characters (like `無効な名前`).

Comment: Unsure why this is happening. I'm using Atom.

Comment: Hey, while this did solve the errrors I had, it didn't fix it for the use case. I need a way to create a factory of errors specifically for my usecase and be able to call `new` for each individual instance. Thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasReggi I've edited to try to answer that, replacing what I had before as a side note.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function Macro( props) {
    return function() { this.macro = props }
}
```

may provide the stated functionality without the use of a fat arrow function (which can't be used as a constructor), or interacting with the prototype chain.

The `new` in a `new Macro` call would be noise and should be omitted.  Including it creates a new Macro instance object prototyped on `Macro.prototype` when `Macro` is called, only to have the instance object discarded because `Macro` returns a (different) function object.